# List of filepaths to router manufacturer's logo on different devices

Tags: image, router, filepath

To start this off, let me introduce my problem. I'm currently working on master thesis, which is based on monitoring and blocking HTTP requests that are originated in **public** internet and destined for devices in **local (private)** network. These requests could be potentionally malicious, as there's no valid reason for websites in public internet to access local network.

Currently I'm working on the small test webpage, which will demonstrate functionality of my work. For that sake, I'm going to use default router IP address list with combination of given filepaths to manufacturer's logos. So, if you happen to view this webpage, the script in the background basically tries every default IP adress from that list and also will try to access router's manufacturer's logo image. Hopefully one of the requests will hit your router and load up the logo, which will be displayed on the webpage demonstrating this "vulnerability". That page won't be accessible online. It will only come packed with my master thesis at the end of my work.

What I'm asking of you, is to provide me information about your router's manufacturer and as well as a filepath to the image logo (if it happens to have one). So, for example something like this: `Asus: /images/New_ui/asustitle.png`.

Getting this location should be easy. Just log in to your router, inspect the page and copy&paste **src** atribute of the `<img>` (in my case: `<img src="images/New_ui/asustitle.png" width="218" height="54" align="left"`>).

I thank very much to those, who decide to help me with that. I also respect if you don't want to share that information, but believe that my intentions are perfectly sane and valid and it's all just for the purposes of my master thesis.

I'll keep extending the list here:

**Asus**

- `/images/New_ui/asustitle.png`

**TP-Link**

- `/images/top1_1.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

For my TP-Link model TL-WR841N the route is `/images/top1_1.jpg`.